# How to use async/await function in the lambda function aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, async-await

Working on a simple project in AWS, I'm using Node js. In my code after every function I have put `setTimeout()`, but what I want is to replace it with async/await function instead of `setTimeout()`.
Is there documentation of how to use the async/await function in lambda for AWS-SDK.

Comment: A quick search yields general examples of async use of the AWS JavaScript SDK, for example [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/using-async-await.html), [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/calling-services-asynchronously.html), and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/using-async-await.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use the **AWS JavaScript 3  DEV Guide**. In this guide, you will find this information here that describes using Asnyc as well:

[Creating and using Lambda functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/lambda-create-table-example.html)